# ADD items to listView

Tags: android, listview

I created a List View in a notification page and i want to add items to this ListView from  DateTimePickerDemo : so this is my  DateTimePickerDemo java code and my Anotification java code

[image]

[image]

And this this is my code

```
public class DateTimePickerDemo extends notification implements OnClickListener, DateTimePickerDialog.DateTimeListener {
/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
View v ;

ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
private MovieAdapter listAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    findViewById(R.id.ButtonTime).setOnClickListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    TextView addtext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Date);
    int i = 1;
    if (view.getId() == R.id.ButtonTime) {
        showDateTimeDialog();
    }
    if (view.getId() == R.id.button) {
        adapter.add(edit.getText().toString()+"  "+addtext.getText().toString());
        edit.setText("");
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}










private void showDateTimeDialog() {
    DateTimePickerDialog pickerDialog = new DateTimePickerDialog(this, false, this);
    pickerDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onDateTimeSelected(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int min, int am_pm) {
    String text = day + "/" + month + "/" + year + " - " + hour + ":" + min;
    if (am_pm != -1)
        text = text + (am_pm == Calendar.AM ? "AM" : "PM");
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.Date)).setText(text);
}



public class notification extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;
int [] movie_poster_resource = {R.drawable.ic_reunion};
String[] reunion_name;
String[] temps_rendez;
MovieAdapter adapter;
View view;
Intent intent;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification);
    listView= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    temps_rendez = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.réunion_temps);
    reunion_name = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.réunion_title);
    int i=0;
    adapter = new MovieAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.patient_name);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    for (String titles: reunion_name)
    {

        MovieDataProvider dataProvider = new MovieDataProvider(movie_poster_resource[0],titles,temps_rendez[i]);
        adapter.add(dataProvider);
        i++;
    }



}


}
public class MovieAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
List list = new ArrayList();
public MovieAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
}

static class DataHandler{

   ImageView Poster;
    TextView title;
    TextView rating;

}
@Override
public void add(Object object) {
    super.add(object);
    list.add(object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return this.list.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row;
    row = convertView;
    DataHandler handler;
    if (convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.patient_name,parent,false);
        handler = new DataHandler();
        handler.Poster = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.patient_picture);
        handler.title = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.patient_name);
        handler.rating = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.temps_rendez_vous);

        row.setTag(handler);
    }else{
        handler = (DataHandler)row.getTag();
    }
    MovieDataProvider dataProvider;
    dataProvider = (MovieDataProvider)this.getItem(position);
    handler.Poster.setImageResource(dataProvider.getPatient_poster_resource());
    handler.title.setText(dataProvider.getPatient_title());
    handler.rating.setText(dataProvider.getTemps());




    return row ;
}
```

}

Comment: If you're adding items, you may wana consider using a RecyclerView

Comment: post your adapter code.\

Comment: you can see it now I add it janki gadhiya